# "Wake for Ethernet network access" no longer works after changing router

Tags: airport, router, wake-on-lan

For years I've used an Apple Airport Extreme router which recently began randomly dropping connections and exhibiting other odd issues. This coupled with slow wireless speeds (by modern standards) led me to buy a new router, a TP-LINK AC1750 (Archer A7).

So far it's awesome, but I've noticed a couple behaviours have changed.

Most significantly, "Wake for Ethernet network access" no longer works on my desktop. It's a Macpro running OSX 10.14.6.  Previously, it would go to sleep, but if I made an attempt to connect via SSH it would wake up.  I could also access it via finder as a network share and even when asleep it would show up on under "Locations" in the finder. Clicking on it would wake the computer. Now, once it's asleep, I need to go physically do something to the computer.

After reading up a bit on the subject, I've now configured DHCP as well as ARP binding so that the machine in question has a fixed LAN IP and I am now able to use commandline util `wakeonlan` to wake up this machine.

Is there a way to get the old behaviour back? How was the Airport Extreme doing this?  I didn't need `wakeonlan` previously - I only had to `ssh` to the machine and it would wake up.  Was the old router doing something special here?

Comment: You would need a Bonjour sleep proxy on the local network. AirPort devices have that feature, as do Apple TV's and HomePods. A Mac that has Internet Sharing enabled also functions as one.

Comment: @LincD. - thanks.  that kinda sucks but it's good information. Unfortunately I don't believe my Mac will be able to go to sleep with Internet Sharing enabled. All the same, can you explain the basics of how to set that up? Maybe post it as an answer.

Comment: I don't know if this'd work, but it might be possible to reconnect the Airport Extreme with its routing functions turned off, and have it continue functioning as a Bonjour sleep proxy. Unless that function's flaking out too... Otherwise, do you have any computers that're always on that could run a sleep proxy like [this one](https://github.com/kfix/SleepProxyServer)?

Comment: @GordonDavisson - both good ideas.  I'd prefer not to have the Airport running for that sole purporse.  I do have an Ubuntu server on the LAN and was looking at that exact repo earlier after reading about sleep proxy servers.  The only issue is that it's very old and the packages in the install instructions aren't exactly available.  Probably others are and maybe it can be tweaked to work on Ubuntu 22 which is what I'm running.  I'll report back here after making an attempt...

Comment: You're right that the Mac won't sleep with Internet Sharing enabled, as otherwise it wouldn't be able to act as a proxy. If you only have the one Mac and you don't want to share its network connection, you should just disable sleep by following the instructions here: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-sleep-and-wake-settings-mchle41a6ccd/mac